# why temperature gradient at the centre of plane wall or spherical container with the heat generator is zero?

Tags: thermodynamics

Heat is generated in a container in the shape of a plane wall according to some equation (the equation doesn't matter); we call it just $q$ here so I use Fourier field equation to get temperature difference between the plane centre line and its surface nl. The Laplacian is $(T)+q/k=0$ and I can solve this DE for sure but can someone explain why $dT/dx=0$ at the centre because I think there would be the temperature difference between a point at the centre and any other point no matter how close to the centre! Am I wrong?  This problem is 1D of course.

Comment: The temperature in the boundary i.e., two ends of the wall, is lower than the temperature of any neighboring point inside the wall and the temperature of any point inside the wall must be finite.

Comment: The temperature at the center is maximum, so its derivative is zero.

Comment: @ChesterMiller indeed , mathematically it makes sense ! but physically doesn't ! cos every point should have different temperature if you write the expresion in terms of delta(T0)-delta(Ti) over delta(x) , then it implies that delta(T0)=delta(Ti) other say every point adjacent to center has the same temperature ! where i make a mistake ?

Comment: There are tiny gradients going away from the center at $-dx/2$ and $+dx/2$ that remove the tiny amount of heat generated within the interval between these locations.  It's just a limiting process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of heat sometimes escapes us because we do not deal with it physically in the sense that it is tangible. I've provided you with the flux equation and the temperature distribution. Here you can see that the flux is 0 at the top because it is being pulled in opposite(competing)directions by Fourier's law. The point x=0 has no width to it. Heat moves away to the right of this point and away to the left of this point and never crosses the point at x=o. This is why you can explain the solution in terms of an insulated boundary condition at x=0.
[image: Temp Distribution]